# Android: Directories & sub-directory listing continuous Activity issue

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I am trying to create a directory listing, which shows the list of the name of the folder. If the user clicks on the Directory name and if that directory contains sub-directories then a new activity will be called listing all the sub-dirs. And this process will continue.
I've created the listing of the first page, but now as it is a continuous looping process, which approach should I use.
Can this parent activity can call itself OR should I use startActivity for result OR ViewFlipper OR anything else. Please suggest.

EDIT [Code Added:]

MainActivity Class

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity implements OnClickListener {

    Button done, cancel, selectAll;

    ListView listView;
    ArrayAdapter<Directory> adapter;
    List<Directory> list;
    HashMap<String, Boolean> checkedMap;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        try {
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            done = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bDone);
            cancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bCancel);
            selectAll = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSelAll);
            done.setOnClickListener(this);
            cancel.setOnClickListener(this);

            new AsyncHandler(this).execute();
            if (list != null) {
                checkedMap = new HashMap<String, Boolean>();
                Iterator<Directory> i = list.iterator();
                while (i.hasNext()) {
                    Directory d = (Directory) i.next();
                    checkedMap.put(d.getName(), d.isSelected());
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        Directory d = list.get(position);
        File[] subDir = d.getFile().listFiles();
        // TODO: UPDATE ACTIVITY
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.bDone:
            // Update CheckedMap in DB
            // Toast.makeText(this, m_checkedMap.values().toString(),
            // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
        case R.id.bCancel:
            this.finish();
            break;
        }
    }

    public class AsyncHandler extends AsyncTask {

        Context context;

        public AsyncHandler(Context c) {
            context = c;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Toast.makeText(context, "In onPreExecute()", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            // .show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object... arg0) {
            getList();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
            // super.onPostExecute(result);
            setListAdapter(new ElementAdapter(context, list));
        }

        private void getList() {
            list = new ArrayList<Directory>();
            File root = new File("/");
            File[] files = root.listFiles();
            for (File f : files) {
                if (f.isDirectory() && !f.isHidden()) {
                    list.add(new Directory(f, f.getName()));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Custom Adapter

```
public class ElementAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private List<Directory> list;

    public ElementAdapter(Context c, List<Directory> list) {
        super(c, R.layout.row, list);
        this.context = c;
        this.list = list;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        protected TextView textView;
        protected CheckBox checkBox;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvElement);
            viewHolder.checkBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
            viewHolder.checkBox
                    .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                                boolean isChecked) {
                            int getPosition = (Integer) buttonView.getTag();
                            list.get(getPosition).setSelected(
                                    buttonView.isChecked());
                        }
                    });
            view.setTag(viewHolder);
            view.setTag(R.id.tvElement, viewHolder.textView);
            view.setTag(R.id.checkBox1, viewHolder.checkBox);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }
        viewHolder.checkBox.setTag(position);
        viewHolder.textView.setText(list.get(position).getName());
        viewHolder.checkBox.setChecked(list.get(position).isSelected());

        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: Simply, use ListView with Custom Adapter to display directories, when new sub directories added to list just notify your custom adapter with new values in list. There is no need of any other activity.

Comment: Hi, thanks for quick reply...although I got what you are saying but I'm quite new to Android especially layouts. I've updated the question with code. Can u please tell me how to do it. ( It will be updated in `onListItemClick` i believe).

Comment: in **onListItemClick**  `setListAdapter(new ElementAdapter(context, list));` but this time **list** contains new sub directories list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to the comment above by "user370305".